# How to further accelerate this acceleration algorithm? Or what might give more accurate digits faster?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Since the late Richard Crandal got me started on it in 2012, I've been using, instead of other acceleration methods,
"THE FIRST ACCELERATION ALGORITHM" from Convergence Acceleration of Alternating Series of Henri Cohen, Fernando Rodriguez Villegas, and Don Zagier found on the first page
[here,](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/exp-math-9/fulltext.pdf) i.e. [image]

to calculate record numbers of digits of the MRB constant. That is, [image: The MRB constant is defined as the upper limit of the partial sums {\displaystyle s_{n}=\sum {k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}k^{1/k}}s{n}=\sum _{{k=1}}^{n}(-1)^{k}k^{{1/k}}].

Having used a fast algorithm to calculate $k^{1/k}$ along with algorithm 1 to compute a little over 5,000,000 digits (giving the same result as (10^5,000,000 - 1) terms of the brute force method), my records are all fully documented [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366628?p_p_auth=a0HHOEWy). I also had only minimal results with an Euler's acceleration method [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/bmmmburns/Published/MRBConstant(1).nb). Simply Beautiful Art suggested the Aitken acceleration method which I used to accelerate brute fore and Eulers with much (but not enough) and no benefit respectively. Simply's suggestion was to add Adkins to my use of the Cohen et al acceleration mentioned at the beginning of this body. My use of it, however, doesn't give a clearcut series that Atkins appears to ask for. Perhaps there is a way to get around that?

Going by the number of people that have visited my record computations post, I presume that there will be a lot of people interested in how I use your answer.

Comment: Are you computing that constant to five million digits ???

Comment: One's got to set the bar somewhere.

Comment: There's more than anyone needs there but here is a link to all of my definitions and calculations: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366628?p_p_auth=yFafom3J

Comment: It would seem the convergence is nearly geometric, and testing it a bit, it would appear as though the [Aitken acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitken's_delta-squared_process) applied to the provided acceleration algorithm effectively gives more digits.

Comment: @ Simply Beautiful Art, so I take it that in the case of summing the $x^{1/x}-1$ in the MRB constant formula, Atkins uses $x^{1/x}-1$, $(x+1)^{1/(x+1)}-1$  and $(x+2)^{1/(x+2)}-1$. (that is according to https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/e3a9c791d5e0d53fad01156e8b11bb51df86431e) But how is Atkins applied to the provided acceleration algorithm?